# Why is the intensity function of $N$-slits interference symmetric?

Tags: waves, interference, diffraction

I'm taking a course of quantum physics and we were asked to plot the intensity function of interference between the waves which exit 20 slits, when the distance between the slits is given by $$ d+A\epsilon_i $$ where $d,A$ are integers and epsilon is a random number between [0,1].

I used Matlab to solve this task. The expression I've entered is given by 
$$ I(\theta)=|Real(\Sigma exp(i\Delta\phi_m))|^2 $$ where the summation goes from m=1 to 20 and the phase is given by $$ \Delta\phi_i=k(nd+A\Sigma\epsilon_i)sin(\theta) $$

and what I've got was a graph which have symmetry about the Intensity axis. I wanted to ask where does this symmetry come from if I used random numbers?

The outcome plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The far-field interference pattern is always symmetric about $\theta=0$ however asymmetric the grating may be.

This is because, for any two slits, the phase difference between them is the same at the same diffraction angle on either side of the normal to the grating. To the left side waves from the left slit will have a phase lead, and to the right side waves from the right slit will have a phase lead, but the phase difference will be the same in both cases. The amplitude and intensity of light on the screen only depends on the phase difference.

The explanation extends to multiple slits.